# Android: ScrollView showing the most updated record once nre record is inflated / added

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I am working on a app where when the user add records, the records would be inflated to the bottom of the ScrollView. I would like to ask how to set the view such that once the user clicks the add button, the scrollView will automatically "slides" and showing the most updated record that was added at the bottom? Many thanks!!

Is it to add to the layout.xml file? The xml coding is as follows:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@color/light_yellow">
      <ScrollView android:id="@+id/SlotScrollView" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"  
         android:layout_span="8"         
         android:padding="0dp">
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/SlotTableLayout" 
               android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent" 
               android:padding="0dp" 
               android:stretchColumns="*"></TableLayout>
      </ScrollView>
   </TableRow>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a scrollview instead of a listview?

Comment: it is because user can inflate row to the scrollview and when it is full, it can scroll down. is it possible to show the most newly inflated row?